# How to run a javascript program on a XAMPP server and save the data from that program on the server?

Tags: javascript, server, xampp, save, jspsych

I wrote a Javascript program using a psychology experiment tool called JSPsych. I need to run the program on a server and have the data produced from the experiment trials saved to the server itself.

I downloaded XAMPP and somewhat succeeded in running the program through XAMPP, but I do not know how to have the data saved.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

[JATOS](http://www.jatos.org/Whats-JATOS.html) might be a solution for you. JATOS cares for the server-side - while jsPsych cares for the client-side (what happens in the browser) and you can easily [turn your experiment into a JATOS study](http://www.jatos.org/jsPsych-and-JATOS.html). Then it has a database (H2 or MySQL) to store your experiment's result data. From your JavaScript code you [connect to JATOS through jatos.js](http://www.jatos.org/Mandatory-lines-in-your-components-HTML.html).

(Disclaimer: I'm the developer behind JATOS)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to setup some kind of server-side script that communicates with a database or writes files to disk. Typically you would call the script with an `XMLHttpRequest` in JavaScript, passing the results of `jsPsych.data.get().json()` or `jsPsych.data.get().csv()` as an argument.

In my lab we currently use [this small PHP library](https://github.com/vassar-cogscilab/php-mysql-save-data) that I wrote to save data from jsPsych experiments. The README provides an overview of how to use it.